# How to remove duplicate elements based date

Tags: python, algorithm, list, data-structures

I am having dictinoary which contains list of list

```
find_dup = {"one":[["1654","raj","425","16-02-2017"],["1654","mo","426","20-02-2017"],["1654","ss","425","20-02-2017"],["1654","vs","427","20-02-2017"],["1654","ss","425","14-02-2017"]]}
```

I want to find duplicated based in list of first and third element

eg

```
["1654","raj","425","16-02-2017"] -> 1654,425
["1654","mo","426","20-02-2017"] -> 1654,426
["1654","ss","425","20-02-2017"] -> 1654,425
["1654","vs","427","20-02-2017"] -> 1654,427
["1654","ss","425","14-02-2017"] -> 1654,425
```

From the above elements it shows 1654,425 are duplicates (since i want to find duplicates based on first and third elements)

So from the above list this list are duplicates

```
["1654","raj","425","16-02-2017"] -> 1654,425
["1654","ss","425","20-02-2017"] -> 1654,425
["1654","ss","425","14-02-2017"] -> 1654,425
```

now from this list we have to remove 2 elements which has older date (last element of list is date)

This 2 list has older date so this should be removed

```
["1654","raj","425","16-02-2017"] -> 1654,425
["1654","ss","425","14-02-2017"] -> 1654,425
```

Results should be this

```
find_dup = {"one":[["1654","mo","426","20-02-2017"],["1654","ss","425","20-02-2017"],["1654","vs","427","20-02-2017"]]}
```

I have python script which iterates through lists but i could not find logic on how to do pop an element if i find duplicate and replace the latest date

This is my script which failed

```
find_dup = {"one":[["1654","raj","425","16-02-2017"],["1654","mo","426","20-02-2017"],["1654","ss","425","20-02-2017"],["1654","vs","427","20-02-2017"],["1654","ss","425","14-02-2017"]]}


for d in find_dup:
    len_d = len(find_dup[d])
    store_array_dup = []
    store_array_ele = {}
    for i in find_dup[d]:

        val = i[0]+"-"+i[1]"-"+i[2]"-"+i[3]
        val_1 = i[0]+"-"+i[2]
        if val_1 in store_array_dup:
            store_array_ele.append(val_1)
        else:
            arrs = []
            arrs.append(val)
            store_array_ele[d] = arrs
```

How could i produce this results

```
find_dup = {"one":[["1654","mo","426","20-02-2017"],["1654","ss","425","20-02-2017"],["1654","vs","427","20-02-2017"]]}
```

Comment: do you want to keep the same order of elements?

Comment: yes because i get that from csv @PawełKordowski

Comment: but in your example result `vs` is after `ss` and the order is different in the input data

Comment: what i mean by order is the element position should remain same like this ["1654","vs","427","20-02-2017"] it should not change order like this ["1654","20-02-2017","427","vs"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your dataset:

```
find_dup = {"one":[
                      ["1654","raj","425","16-02-2017"],
                      ["1654","mo","426","20-02-2017"],
                      ["1654","ss","425","20-02-2017"],
                      ["1654","vs","427","20-02-2017"],
                      ["1654","ss","425","14-02-2017"]
                   ]
            }
```

You can make a new dict base on your dataset with new key based on first and third element and sort it by date:

```
from datetime import datetime
lst = sorted(find_dup['one'] , key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[3], "%d-%m-%Y"))

new_dict = {(item[0], item[2]): item for item in lst}

print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
>>> print(new_dict.values())
[['1654', 'vs', '427', '20-02-2017'], ['1654', 'mo', '426', '20-02-2017'], ['1654', 'ss', '425', '20-02-2017']]
```

Comment: but see the date for ['1654', 'ss', '425', '14-02-2017'] but it want this ["1654","ss","425","20-02-2017"]

Comment: You can do this whit sorting data, I changed it.

Comment: but you should cast `x[3]` into date first, alphabetic sorting is not correct here

Comment: could u please expain what is x[3] and how the code works so that it would be easy for me to automate and learn?

Comment: I would also vote for using a tuple `(item[0], item[2])` instead of `item[0] + item[2]` as a key

Comment: @Mounarajan x[3] is date in your dataset and sorted(), make a sorted list base on that, so after that, You can make a new dict with this key **(item[0], item[2])**

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to sort your list by tuple (first element, third element and date) and keep the smallest date first and then group the sorted list by first and third element and finally select first element from each subgroup:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from datetime import datetime

find_dup = {"one":[["1654","raj","425","16-02-2017"],["1654","mo","426","20-02-2017"],["1654","ss","425","20-02-2017"],["1654","vs","427","20-02-2017"],["1654","ss","425","14-02-2017"]]}

find_dup_sorted = sorted(find_dup["one"], key=lambda x: (x[0], x[2], datetime.strptime(x[3], "%d-%m-%Y")))

result = {"one": []}

for k, g in groupby(find_dup_sorted, key=itemgetter(0, 2)):
    result["one"].append(next(g))

print result
```

Comment: could u please explain what is it doing i have to automate this?

Answer (score 0):

First solve the problem for a list of list:

```
def mounarajan_no_dup(l):
    dedup = {}
    for i in l:
        k = (i[0], i[3])
        if k not in dedup:
            dedup[k] = i
        else :
            j3 = dedup[k][3]
            jdate = j3[6:10] + j3[3:5] + j3[0:2]
            i3 = i[3]
            idate = i3[6:10] + i3[3:5] + i3[0:2]
            if jdate < idate:
                dedup[k] = i
    return dedup.values()
```

And then apply it to every entry of `find_dup`.

```
find_dup = {
    "one":[
        ["1654","raj","425","16-02-2017"],
        ["1654","mo","426","20-02-2017"],
        ["1654","ss","425","20-02-2017"],
        ["1654","vs","427","20-02-2017"],
        ["1654","ss","425","14-02-2017"]]}
for d in find_dup:
    find_dup[d] = mounarajan_no_dup(find_dup[d])
find_dup
{'one': [['1654', 'ss', '425', '14-02-2017'], ['1654', 'raj', '425', '16-02-2017'], ['1654', 'mo', '426', '20-02-2017']]}
```